# Removing Ubuntu from a default O.S when starting PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have installed ubuntu alongside windows, on starting it, the computer starts in Ubuntu. I would want to have the option of selecting which operating system to use.

Comment: you dont get 10 sec to choose which OS to boot? just like in this image ? http://davidesalerno.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/grub.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Open and edit `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`.
You will see the following contents:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

You can change the `GRUB_DEFAULT` from 0 to any number, corresponding to the entry in the GRUB bootup menu (first entry is 0, second is 1, etc.)

Set the value of the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` as 10 seconds if it has not been set. You can force the grub menu to show by commenting out the two `GRUB_HIDDEN` lines with a `#` at the beginning of the line.

After saving the changes, run

`sudo update-grub`

Comment: That doesn't allow the user to select the OS on boot.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, open a Terminal and enter `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`.

Now you should see a line which says `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`, meaning it'll wait 0s to boot the default OS. Set this to another value, e.g. 10 and save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Now apply the changes with `sudo update-grub`.